# Can I connect Garmin Oregon 600 to my Pi B+

Tags: usb, gps

Seems simple enough to try but I can't find my GPS unit at the moment. I'm also not finding anything online that suggests this is possible.

I want to connect my Oregon 600 to my Pi B+ and process the NMEA sentences streaming from the device. I will either

- a) do nothing & only save the data to the pi's card,
- b) use python to process onboard the pi,
- c) offload the data to a service.

For now, I want to see the NMEA sentences on the pi. I'll figure out which method to use for processing later.

Is this possible? Any additional software necessary?

Comment: What interfaces, e.g. serial/USB does the Oregon 600 have over which it can send NMEA sentences?

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no point to connect expensive and power-hungry Oregon 600, you should definitely choose BU-353-S4 (SiRF4 chipset), it's plug-and-play solution, that powers up from USB port and even has the built-in magnet for mounting on the car roof top.

From the software standpoint you'll need to install `gpsd`, but there are plenty of tutorials on the web, so I don't delve into that.